# How to get response code from google api oauth2 in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP. Redirect URL given in Google API Console:

```
Redirect URIs:  http://localhost/testgmail/index.php/main/gmail_invite
```

Following code shows me Request For Permission page. When I click Allow Access it takes me to

```
http://localhost/testsaav/index.php/main/gmail_invite?code=4/CXD462cen-oEBe1GaHIH90hjqb2X.QpVsg7mG4AUXaDn_6y0ZQNgaCVLxeAI
```

and it gives me error page not found.

How should I get it to Controller method

```
function gmail_invites()
{
   $data = $this->input->get('code');
}
```

Comment: Err... please describe the problem in detail. What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried to do? What have you obtained. What are you expecting to obtain.

Comment: @SilviuG codeigniter get method is not working for me. i am using $this->input->get('code');